# Delete lines above and below a date pattern which is at the end of line

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with lines as below and would like to delete lines above and below except for date starting with `07-07-2017 13:01`.

```
xyz here there 07-07-2017 12:01:40
smith jones edward 07-07-2017 13:01:40
abc def ghi jkl 07-07-2017 13:02:40
kqr thg fgh lkj 07-07-2017 14:01:40
```

Comment: Did you try `grep`-ing the timestamp ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
grep '07-07-2017 13:01' fileName > newFile
```

Have a look at

`man grep`